# Python 3 Code works interactively, but not when I run my code from a .py file

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to programming, and new to Python. I am running Python 3 on Windows 10, and I am having a strange problem. I built the following script, and it doesn't work:

```
def count_item(sequence, item):
    return sequence.count(item)

count_item([1,2,1,1], 1)
```

When I run it, it comes up empty. Not so much as an error, or the "none" that Python likes to give.

However, when I run it from the interactive shell:

```
>>> item = 1
>>> sequence = [1,2,1,1]
>>> sequence.count(item)
3
```

I am guessing that this has something to do with how functions work on a deep level in Python, but I am just not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might need to print count_item, rather than just calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REPL, or interactive shell, is built to be *interactive*. One way that is manifested is that you don't need to `print` variables and other objects - you can just type their name, hit Enter, and the relevant info shows up.

However, when actually *running* a program, you need to explicitly call the `print()` function in order to make anything show up on the screen. `return` just returns a value to the calling function or statement. So, for your code, modify the last line to:

```
print(count_item([1,2,1,1], 1))
```

Comment: Matt, I appreciate you thoughtful and kind response. I am new to coding, but forgetting "print" means I need to call it for the night! Haha.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Thanks for all your help. Coding has been a steep learning curb, but I know it will work out if I stay at it. Thanks for pushing me along.